# What is the use of void in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5, flash-cs3

What is the use of `void` in Action Script 3.0?

Can any one give brief explanation with example?

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280132/what-is-the-point-of-void-in-as3/4280167#4280167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function type. It means that it doesn't return any data
By default Flash always expect to return a value. If you write a function like this for example:
ActionScript Code:

```
function myFunction(){

}
```

Flash assumes that returning a value is still possible and so watch for it which uses ressources. When you specify :void you are actually telling Flash to not expect any return value so Flash does not waste resources watching for it.

Comment: It's `:void` in AS3, no capital V :).

Answer (score 3):

**void** is an actionscript keyword, used to define **no** return type in function signature, and force compiler to ristrict/check it

eg

```
public function func():void
{
  //do some thing
}
```

above function retuns nothing

Hopefully this will helps

Comment: undefined return type is func():*.

Comment: right, better to say no return type or not returning any thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for me to remember it is that it is a function that carries out an action (in other words does something) rather than returns something.

Example:

```
function myFunction(event:MouseEvent): void   
{ this.play; //or some other action}
//the above function returns nothing


function mySum(a:int, b:int): int
{var myresult:int = a+b;
return myresult;}
//the above function would return the sum of two integers that you passed into it
```

Comment: what? "myFuntion" will return the "play" comment... 

Please.. take me deeper.. I didn't yet get..