# AS3 Flash how to save score in game and display on different frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a trivia game that has 3 rounds per level. On the frame while playing the game you can see a box with the current score and when the user has completed the round they are taken to another frame where you can see the score for all three rounds. I can't seem to get  the score to display correctly. Here's an image roughly illustrating how I would like the score displayed.

[image]

Here's the code I have on round1

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    //Button 
    btn_six.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPressHandler);

    btn_six.buttonMode = true;
    btn_six.useHandCursor = true;

    function onPressHandler(myEvent:MouseEvent){
    trace('Press');
    btn_six.gotoAndPlay(5);
    }

    var saveDataObject:SharedObject;
    var currentScore:int;

    init();

    function init():void{

saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test");
currentScore = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, saveData);

if(saveDataObject.data.savedScore == null){
    trace("No saved data yet.");
    saveDataObject.data.savedScore = currentScore;
} else {
    trace("Save data found.");
    loadData();
}
    }


    function saveData(e:Event):void{
        saveDataObject.data.savedScore = currentScore;
        trace("Data Saved!");
        saveDataObject.flush();
        trace(saveDataObject.size);
    }

    function loadData():void{
        currentScore = saveDataObject.data.savedScore;
        trace("Data Loaded!");
    }







    var questions:Array=['"I look like a dangling parsnip in this!" she cried. "I will never __________ these jeans!',
                 "Tell the freckled parrot to put his car in __________.",
                 "When purchasing a buttercream trowel, always choose one made of __________.",
                 "Everybody has a cracked snowflake. The question is, __________ one is yours? ",
                 "Standing at the dock, the loopy basket watched the cruise ship set __________ without him. ",];
    var answers:Array=[   ["wear","where"], ["idle","idol"], ["steel","steal"] ,[ "which","witch"] ,[ "sail","sale"] ];




     var qno=0;var rnd1; var rnd2;
      tick.visible=false;cross.visible=false;incorrect0.visible=false;incorrect1.visible=false;incorrect2.visible=false;incorrect3.visible=false;
    var right_answers=0;
    var wrong_answers=0;


    function change_question(){
if(tick.visible){right_answers++;}
if(cross.visible){wrong_answers++;}
if(qno==questions.length){gotoAndPlay(2);}else{
tick.visible=false;cross.visible=false;
rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);
rnd2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
q.text=questions[rnd2];
if(questions[rnd2]=="x"){change_question();}
questions[rnd2]="x";
enable_disable(1);
if(rnd1==1){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];}
if(rnd1==2){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][1];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][0];}
//if(rnd1==3){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][1];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][2];opt3.text=answers[rnd2][0];}
if(wrong_answers==0){incorrect0.visible=true;}
if(wrong_answers==1){incorrect1.visible=true;}
if(wrong_answers==2){incorrect2.visible=true;}
if(wrong_answers==3){incorrect3.visible=true;}
if(wrong_answers==3){gotoAndPlay(3);}
}}

    function enable_disable(a){
if(a==0){shade1.mouseEnabled=false;shade2.mouseEnabled=false;}
if(a==1){shade1.mouseEnabled=true;shade2.mouseEnabled=true;}}

    change_question();

    function ButtonAction1(eventObject:MouseEvent) {qno++;change_question();} 

    shade1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction2);
    shade2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction3);


    function ButtonAction2(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==1)   {tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade1.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade1.y}
qno++;change_question();
}
    function ButtonAction3(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==2){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade2.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade2.y}
qno++;change_question();
}


    stop();
```

On round 1 cleared the code looks like this:

```
    ra.text=right_answers +"/5";

    if(wrong_answers==3){gotoAndPlay(3);}
```

The code is the same on round 2 as round 1 
and here's the code on round 2 cleared:

```
    ra2.text=right_answers_r2 +"/10";

    if(wrong_answers==3){gotoAndPlay(3);}

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
    function myFunction(event:Event) {
        trace("Do Something");
        showScoreText();
    }

    function showScoreText():void{
        MovieClip(root).round1.loadData();
        ra.text = MovieClip(root).round1.loadData("");
        trace("Score text visible");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `loadData` function to:

```
function loadData(){
    currentScore = saveDataObject.data.savedScore;
    trace("Data Loaded!");
    return currentScore;
    //^One does not simply expect something returned without returning anything
}
```

and there's no accepted parameter, so change

```
ra.text = MovieClip(root).round1.loadData("");
```

to

```
ra.text = MovieClip(root).round1.loadData();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your suggestion and I'm getting this error: 1051:Return value must be undefined. I'm not sure what to do about this, any suggestions?

Comment: @user2933373 Sorry, `void` tells the function `not to return anything`, so just remove it (edited in answer, read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591580/what-is-the-use-of-void-in-as3))

Comment: Thanks! That error disappeared, but a different one came up. 

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at bubblingdoubles_107_fla::round2_19/showScoreText()[bubblingdoubles_107_fla.round2_19::frame2:58]
 at bubblingdoubles_107_fla::round2_19/myFunction()[bubblingdoubles_107_fla.round2_19::frame2:54]

It's telling me that showScoreText();   and   MovieClip(root).round1.loadData();      are null, but I'm not sure how to fix this. What should I do?

Comment: @user2933373 Tell me the code at line `58` and `54`, please

Comment: The code at line 54 is showScoreText();
The code at line 58 is MovieClip(root).round1.loadData();

Comment: @user2933373 Check if the `loadData` function is defined in your `round1` MovieClip

Answer (score 0):

try this,

just assume you have completed round 1 and your currentScore is 10 now you are going to round 2 that is on frame 2 and you have a score textfield in the stage now you have to append the text like this `score_txt.appendText(String(currentScore)+"\n");` This helps to see both scores round 1 & round 2 keep doing this for all round. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the currentScore at the end of the each rounds in associative array and display it.

```
var scorearray:Array = [{scored:5, outof:10},{scored:10, outof:20},{scored:20, outof:30}];
function displayScore():void
{
    for(var i:int=0;i<scorearray.length; i++)
    {
        var texts:TextField = new TextField();
            texts.text = scorearray[i].scored +"/" + scorearray[i].outof;
            texts.y = i * 20 + 30;
            addChild(texts)
    }
}

displayScore();
```