# Going to next frames in Action Script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I am having a problem with AS 3.0
When you click on a door. You'll move to the next frame.
In the next frame i tried the same. But its not working.

This is the code:

FRAME1;

```
stop();

deur1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, frame2);
function frame2(event:MouseEvent)

    {
gotoAndStop(2)
        }// This part works. I am now in frame 2.
```

FRAME2:

```
deur2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, frame3);
function frame3(event:MouseEvent)

    {
gotoAndStop(3)
        }
```

deur1=door1. deur2=door2
    The doors are a Buttons.
When i run this project. All i see are all my frames for each FPS.

This is the compile error i get:
Compile errors

Scene 1, layer 'layer1' Frame 2, line 1: 1023 Incompatible override

Scene 1, layer 'layer1' Frame 2, Line 1: 1021 Duplicate function definition.

Scene 1, layer 'layer1' Frame 2, Line 3: 1000 Ambiguous reference to frame2

MainTimeLine, Line2: 1000 ambiguous reference to frame2.

Comment: You didn't forget to put the stop(); in your frame2, right?

Comment: That not needed. As i do: GotoAndStop(2) for going to frame 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get those Compile errors because of the names you are using for the functions. It seems "*frame2*" and "*frame3*" are reserved names. Try to use more descriptive names for your functions, it will help you (and others) to understand your code, and this way you are less likely to run into errors like these.

Try this (I also corrected the formatting to improve readability):

On frame 1:

```
stop();

deur1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_to_frame2);

function go_to_frame2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  gotoAndStop(2)
}
```

On frame 2:

```
deur2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, go_to_frame3);

function go_to_frame3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndStop(3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This works great now! May i ask why the :Void is also added?

Comment: void is added so people (and the compiler) can read the function line and know what this function is expected to return. void in this case since it doesn't return anything. it does it little bit of code and ends. toString() for example returns a String (obviously) so that would be written `function toString():String { return "hello"; }`

Comment: I'll let someone else answer you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280132/what-is-the-point-of-void-in-as3  The third answer is the more informative

Answer (score 0):

Why not make more generic functions? If you have declared the functions in your first frame, then you can access them from other frames. Like this:

```
// Frame 1
function goPrevFrame(event : MouseEvent) : void
{
    nextFrame(); // or gotoAndStop(currentFrame +1);
}

function goNextFrame(event : MouseEvent) : void
{
    prevFrame(); // or gotoAndStop(currentFrame -1);
}

stop();
deur1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goNextFrame);
```

---

```
// Frame 2
stop();
deur2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goNextFrame);
```

---

```
// Frame 3
stop();
deur3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goNextFrame);
```

---

One thing to keep in mind is that you are not removing any of the event listeners, so you should use weak references.

```
deur3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goNextFrame, false, 0, true);
```

[Clarifications regarding weak references in actionscript listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231636/clarifications-regarding-weak-references-in-actionscript-listeners/7231838#7231838)